# Получить текущую строку из таблицы Access

Tags: access, vba, office

Есть Макрос, который срабатывает по определенному нажатию кнопки.

Как я могу через VBA получить текущую строчку в которой находится пользователь и обработать ее в модуле, который вызывает макрос?

Никакие формы я не использую, пользователь работает непосредственно в таблицах.

Метод я нашел `Screen.ActiveDatasheet` , но не понимаю как из него вытянуть названия полей и перебрать все значения в строке.

Comment: Может тут нужен метод CurrentRecord?

Comment: Да, вы почти правы. Я воспользовался RecordSet и там нашел нужную колонку.

Answer (score 1):

Смастерил такое решение:

```
  Function main(FieldName As String)
    Dim objDatasheet As Variant
    objDatasheet = Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Recordset.Fields(FieldName).Value
    If IsNull(objDatasheet) Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.FollowHyperlink objDatasheet
    End Function
```